# Integral of a function and function of an integral

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

For a probability distribution $\mu$, and real valued function $f$, when is $\left| \int^1_0 f(x) \mu(x) dx - f(\int^1_0 x \mu(x) dx)\right|$ small? For example, intuitively, if $\mu$ is sharply peaked about the mean, and not too skewed, and $f$ is not too wiggly, then the above difference looks like it will be small. Can we be more specific? Provide bounds on the difference given certain properties of $f,\mu$?

Comment: What is $\theta$?

Comment: I've edited the expression. This was something of an artefact of switching from writing things the statisticians do. Theta was a random variable whose probability is given by mu.

Comment: Are you sure that's the notation you mean (as in Daoust's answer)? And not perhaps $\int_0^1 f(x) \mu(dx)$ ? But that also would not make much sense since $\int_0^1  \mu(dx) =1$. Perhaps $\left |\mathsf{E}[ f(X)] - f(\mathsf{E}[ X]) \right |$ ?

Comment: You're right. I think I'm trying to be too clever. The question was inspired by the relation between the expectation of a function and the function of an expectation, but I wanted to ask it in a more general way. I've edited the question again. This time I think it should be clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a reasonable estimate if you assume $f$ twice differentiable with a bounded second derivative on the support of $\mu$.

Your random variable here takes values in $[0,1]$ but that is not so important. So take any real random variable $X$ with average $m$ and of finite variance $\sigma^2<+\infty$. Assume that $|f''|\leq a$ on the support of $X$. Then with $\lambda=f'(m)$ we have the following inequality on the support of $\mu$:
$$ |f(X)-f(m) -\lambda (X-m)| \leq \frac{a}2  |X-m|^2.$$
Taking averages we get
$$ |{\mathbf E}(f(X)) - f({\mathbf E} X)|\leq 
|{\mathbf E} (f(X)-f(m)-\lambda (X-m))| \leq \frac{a}{2} \sigma^2. $$

Comment: Hi this looks great. I think I understand the second inequality, but could you explain the first? It looks like a Taylor expansion, but how do you know which way the inequality will go if you ignore the small higher order terms? Maybe it's just me being slow...

Comment: Also, something goes wrong if you let $f$ be concave (i.e. second derivative negative everywhere). Then you have a negative number apparently larger than an absolute value?

Comment: It is Taylor's theorem with the Lagrange form for the remainder (you may look it up on the wiki page for Taylor's theorem). For your second remark, note that $|f''|\leq a$ implies that $a$ is non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

@H.H.Rugh already gave you a nice answer but it may be worth adding a minor thing. The minimum of

$$
\left| \int f(x) \mu(x) dx - f \left( \int x \mu(x) dx  \right) \right|
$$

is zero (it is by definition a non-negative expression). You obtain exactly zero if 
$\mu(x) = \delta(x-a)$, where $\delta$ is the [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).
In fact, just by using the defining property of the Dirac delta,

$$
 \int f(x) \delta(x-a) dx = f(a)
$$

and

$$
\int x \delta(x-a) dx = a
$$

Comment: This is, actually, what  I want to use this approximation for: to replace an integral that's slow to compute with a closed-form expression based on a delta function.